# What can replace Linq2Xsd?

Tags: c#, rest, soap, contract-first, linq-to-xsd

We've been using Linq2Xsd for a decade. For enforcing centralised control internal data structures and external interfaces we found it invaluable. Our team size is about 10 developers in 3 sub-teams. We really like the way you can branch the code, edit the contract, assign it to a developer and give them written description of the DC changes and required functionality
However, it's getting to the point where the technologies we use are long in the tooth and we can't guarantee that they are going to continue functioning in the future.

However, we not willing to give up the contract-first nature of our workflow. (In our particular department) It  just works too well.

Our "back end" system consists of:

1. A Linq To Sql Data Access Layer, generated from the database (to be replaced with Devart's LinqConnect)
2. A Linq To Xsd powered Business Logic Layer, generated from the master contract XSD, both public entry points and public data structures. Also validates incoming XML against the XSD
3. Many interface projects that pull the WSDL from the BLL an auto generates a service, be it SOAP or REST.

Here are the use cases that need to be fill by one or many, well supported or at least open source, add-ons to Visual Studio 2012 and/or Visual Studio 2017.

A method of creating a structured document, of a well know type, that can be read at build time and is used to create the public static methods and public data classes exposed by the project.

Incoming data, either binary or text document, can be verified against said contract.

Comment: Since LINQ to XSD is apparently open source, can't you just subsume it into your systems?

Comment: Yes, in fact we do. We've patched our own bits and bobs into it.
I just want a backup to our backup.
Also it hopefully means a large development community at around a more popular solution